# window.removeEventListener not working in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to block tab refresh/closing when a user is editing the page. This is stored in state. I have a useEffect that is triggered whenever the isEditing state changes:

```
const [isEditing, setIsEditing] = useState<boolean>(false);

const handleBrowserCloseReload = (e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    return (e.returnValue = '');
  };

useEffect(() => {
    if (isEditing) {
      window.addEventListener('beforeunload', handleBrowserCloseReload);
    } else {
      console.log('remove');
      window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', handleBrowserCloseReload);
    }
  }, [isEditing]);
```

The problem is even when the 'remove' is logged to the console, I still get the prompt to save changes. Another question is does anyone know the type of the event for this? I do not want to leave it as "any"

Comment: you are using a Functional component without memoizing handleBrowserCloseReload. On each render your handlleBrowserBrowserCloseReload reference will change. So when you remove the event listener, you are not using the same reference as when it was added. Since handleBrowserCloseReload has no dependency on the component, you can just move it outside, so its reference doesn't change

Answer (score 1):

Don't bother with an `else` case, just return [a "cleanup" function](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#cleaning-up-an-effect) that removes the handler. When the component re-renders, the cleanup function will run. If you only attach when `isEditing` is true, then when it is `false` it won't get added. Plus you have the benefit that if that component unmounts but the page isn't unloaded, the cleanup will also run.

Just make sure to define your `handleBrowserCloseReload` handler within the `useEffect` hook so you can reuse the reference.

```js
const [isEditing, setIsEditing] = useState<boolean>(false);

useEffect(() => {
    const handleBrowserCloseReload = (e: any) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      return (e.returnValue = '');
    };

    if (isEditing) {
      window.addEventListener('beforeunload', handleBrowserCloseReload);
    }
    
    return () => {
      console.log('remove');
      window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', handleBrowserCloseReload);
    };
}, [isEditing]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Anyone finding this similar issue, it was fixed with memoizing the handleBrowserCloseReload function:

```
const handleBrowserCloseReload = useMemo(() => {
    return (e: any) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      return (e.returnValue = '');
    };
  }, []);
```